# Using an except statement with Alias tables

Tags: sql-server

I probably didn't label that right but am not all that great at sql.  The short of the problem is I am having to find parts that are used to make up a product, but are use ONLY for that product and not any other product.  I was trying to accomplish this with e except statement but kept getting an error with the end and i'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
Select A.Component_Part From (Select * From (SELECT T.Component_Part, View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1.FGITEM, IM.IM_Inv_Type
FROM  IM INNER JOIN
         View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2 AS View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1 ON IM.IM_Part_Nbr = View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1.FGITEM RIGHT OUTER JOIN
             (SELECT Component_Part
            FROM  View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2
            WHERE (FGITEM = 'SPZ-9')) AS T ON View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1.Component_Part = T.Component_Part
WHERE (View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1.FGITEM <> 'SPZ-9') AND (T.Component_Part NOT LIKE '%30-') and IM.IM_Inv_Type = 'F') AS A

Join 
(Select * From (SELECT C.Component_Part, View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1.FGITEM, IM.IM_Inv_Type
FROM  IM INNER JOIN
         View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2 AS View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1 ON IM.IM_Part_Nbr = View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1.FGITEM RIGHT OUTER JOIN
             (SELECT Component_Part
            FROM  View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2
            WHERE (FGITEM = 'SPZ-9')) AS C ON View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1.Component_Part = C.Component_Part
WHERE (View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1.FGITEM = 'SPZ-9') AND (C.Component_Part NOT LIKE '%30-') and IM.IM_Inv_Type = 'F') AS B

Except 

Select * From (SELECT T.Component_Part, View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1.FGITEM, IM.IM_Inv_Type
FROM  IM INNER JOIN
         View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2 AS View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1 ON IM.IM_Part_Nbr = View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1.FGITEM RIGHT OUTER JOIN
             (SELECT Component_Part
            FROM  View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2
            WHERE (FGITEM = 'SPZ-9')) AS T ON View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1.Component_Part = T.Component_Part
WHERE (View_BOM_FG_ALL_v2_1.FGITEM <> 'SPZ-9') AND (T.Component_Part NOT LIKE '%30-') and IM.IM_Inv_Type = 'F') AS A
```

Comment: (1) Please format your SQL. (2) And what is  the error?

Comment: Fixed the code format in question sorry about that.  The error is: Incorrect syntax near 'End Of File'.  Expecting ')', EXCEPT, or UNION.

Comment: The query has too many `SELECT` statements and parenthesis. You can try to simplify it via CTEs.

Comment: Doesn't resolve the issue which appears to be with when I add in the Except statement.

Comment: The error is "near" `except`, but not necessarily the `except` keyword itself. How about `join ... as B` with no conditions?